# Analyse core dump file redhat 7.0

Tags: rhel, core-dump

We have a process that keeps producing a core dump file but not even sure which process. I have followed instructions to use the crash utility to analyse the core dump file. I had to install a new repo and install crash. Now it is running I get this:

`crash: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux and /home/user/d336599/core.26061 do not match!`

Any idea the solution?

Comment: The `crash` utility is for analyzing kernel crashes, not core dumps. You would typically use `gdb` for analyzing a core dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `file` command on the core dump, it should be able to tell you the name of the executable that produced the core dump file.

Then `gdb <executable file> <core dump file>` will start up `gdb`, and the `bt` command in `gdb` will produce a backtrace of the program crash.

But if the debugging symbols have been stripped out of the executable, you'll find that the backtrace will not be very informative. In that case, you might have to find a separate debugging symbol table file for that executable (version must match exactly) and add the `-s <symbol table file>` to the gdb command invocation.

If the core dump is truncated, you're most likely running out of disk space (as you stated in the comments). The core file name `/home/user/d336599/core.26061` indicates you're probably using RHEL7 sysctl default values `kernel.core_pattern = "core"` and `kernel.core_uses_pid = 1`. By specifying an absolute pathname in `kernel.core_pattern` sysctl, you can redirect core dumps to another disk with more space. Just remember to make sure the directory is writeable for the user that owns the program that is dumping the core.

See [`man 5 core`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) for more information on how you can use `kernel.core_pattern` to specify where core dump files will be generated and how to name them.

Comment: The file command didn't help but gdb without the executable file did help, thank you. File command was complaining the core dump is truncated. The machine is allocated 128GB ram and the disk is 64GB so core dumps fill up the disk.